# Replace value between brackets

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a String stored in a table with two logic gates which looks like `1*((CUBL>1)*((DIFL>1)*1))`.

This Variable names are parsed with values from another table e.g. `1*((1150>1)*((0>1)*1))`. I need to replace the values between brackets with another string e.g. `IIf(1150>0,1,0)` , `IIf(0>1,1,0)`. I was wondering how i would go about replacing these values.

Comment: Can't you store those values instead of the whole expression? If not, you could at least store the expression as `{VAL1}*(({VAL2}>{VAL3})*(({VAL4}>{VAL5})*{VAL6}))`

Comment: T-SQL isn't meant for parsing. What real problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: This sounds like a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you try to solve X thinking the solution is Y so you ask for help on Y. What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have edited my question to properly explain what i mean. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: My question stands. I don't see a replacement here, I see an attempt to call one script function from another. This would be easy if you used eg. user defined functions, but you've stored function's body as plain text. Instead of modifying your parsing logic, you want to replace the function parameters with the body of another function. Not a good idea

Comment: all i want to know is how to replace the logic gate so that it returns a 1 or a 0 based on the outcome